# Ignore media url on PHP

Tags: php, web, filter, web-crawler, delimiter

Is there any way to ignore all url that contains media?
I'm using this line:

```
preg_match_all("/((?:http|https):\/\/(?:www\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,15}\.+[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}){1,}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-\?\&\:\%\,\!\;]*))/", $content, $matches);
```

So, I need to ignore this links (and all media type):

```
mydomain.com/content.jpg 

mydomain.com/content.gif

mydomain.com/content.svg

...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create an array of items you want to skip and filter URL's on the basis of that array and then validate URL if it satisfied the first condition. I hope this will work for you...

```
<?php 
$media = array("mp3", "mp4", "mov", "flv", "wmv", "avi", "png", "gif", "jpg", "bmp");
$media_imp = implode('|', $media);

$urls = array('http://www.example.com/image.jpg','http://www.example.com/hello.mp3','http://www.example.com/content.png','http://www.example.com/content.php');

foreach($urls as $url)
{
    if(!preg_match('/^.*\.('.$media_imp.')$/i', $url))
    {
       $regex ='/(?:http|https)?(?:\:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z]+)(?:\/.*)?/im';
       if(preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)) 
       {
            echo "URL Without Media : ".$url;
            echo "<br>";
       } 
    }
}
?>
```

## LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/580044)

Comment: That's what I've been searching. Thanks!

Comment: Great ;) Glad to help you ;)